# Number of methods in each module

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm facing the [65K methods issue](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) in my Android project and I want to view the size of each module that composes my project. Is there a tool that I can use to find this information?

The result I'm looking for is something like this:

- Module 1 -> 10K methods
- Module 2 -> 43K methods
- Module 3 -> 34K methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [tool on github](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts). This tool counts methods in an Android DEX file.